# Finding the function of a graph with given non-linear coordinates? (regression)

Tags: graphing-functions, regression, data-analysis, analytic-functions

I plotted a graph which shows the behavior of a working engine: RPM as $x$ against time as $y$, around 4000 $(x,y)$ points are imported from the experiment data.

I am trying to find an expression which fits the graph and can be used further with a multi-body simulation to simulate the process.

The real question is: which function would be best representing the experimental behavior of the graph?

I tried the curve fitting tool from Matlab and Lagrangian interpolation but not satisfying the graph. A brief idea about a choice of function to use and its procedure and how the graph can be analyzed would help me understand analyzing my data in future in a better way.

[image]

Note: The noise from 0-1.3 seconds can be assumed constant.

Comment: Lagrangian interpolation, despite the name, is almost never good for interpolation. Your function starts as constant and then turns into something like $\cos\omega t\cdot e^{-\beta t}$.

Comment: I am looking for an expression which can be embeded into a multibody simulation. So how can we fuse the piece wise functions or any exponential functions into a single expression defining the behavior of variables ?

Comment: The period looks to be getting longer. Could it be something Bessel like?

Comment: Yeah, a rough estimate still defining the behaviour would do.